# How do I mock Node.js fetch HTTP requests/responses in Node 18?

Tags: node.js, http, mocking, fetch, nock

I am using the new (as of version 18) Node.js "fetch" API to perform HTTP requests e.g.

```js
const response = await fetch(SOMEURL)
const json = await response.json()
```

This works, but I want to "mock" those HTTP requests so that I can do some automated testing and be able to simulate some HTTP responses to see if my code works correctly.

Normally I have used the excellent [nock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock) package alongside Axios to mock HTTP requests, but it doesn't appear to work with `fetch` in Node 18.

So how can I mock HTTP requests and responses when using `fetch` in Node.js?

Answer (score 14):

Using [Node 18.15.0](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/test.html#mocking) I was able to do the following without any third-party lib:

```
import assert from 'node:assert'
import { describe, it, mock } from 'node:test'


describe('Class', () => {
    it('fetch stuff', async () => {
        const json = () => { 
            return {
                key: 'value'
            }
        }
        mock.method(global, 'fetch', () => {
            return { json, status: 200 }
        })

        const response = await fetch()
        assert.strictEqual(response.status, 200)

        const responseJson = await response.json()
        assert.strictEqual(responseJson.key, 'value')

        mock.reset()
    })
})
```

Comment: Interesting technique! So mock.method intecercepts the function call and returns any data you like. My answer intercepts at the network level, so fetch still thinks it's making a network call but it gets intercepted and fed dummy responses.

Answer (score 3):

Node 18's `fetch` function isn't built on the Node.js [http](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/http.html) module like most HTTP libraries (including Axios, request etc) - it's a total rewrite of an HTTP client built on the lower-level "net" library called [undici](https://www.npmjs.com/package/undici). As such, "nock" cannot intercept requests made from the `fetch` function (I believe the team are looking to fix this, but at the time of writing, Nock 13.2.9, Nock does not work for `fetch` requests).

The solution is to use a MockAgent that is built into the [undici](https://www.npmjs.com/package/undici) package.

Let's say your code looks like this:

```
// constants
const U = 'http://127.0.0.1:5984'
const DB = 'users'

const main = async () => {

  // perform request
  const r = await fetch(U + '/' + DB)

  // parse response as JSON
  const j = await r.json()
  console.log(j)
}

main()
```

This code makes a real HTTP request to a CouchDB server running on localhost.

To mock this request, we need to add `undici` into our project:

```
npm install --save-dev undici
```

and add some code to intercept the request:

```js
// constants
const U = 'http://127.0.0.1:5984'
const DB = 'users'

// set up mocking of HTTP requests
const { MockAgent, setGlobalDispatcher } = require('undici')
const mockAgent = new MockAgent()
const mockPool = mockAgent.get(U)
setGlobalDispatcher(mockAgent)

const main = async () => {
  // intercept GET /users requests
  mockPool.intercept({ path: '/' + DB }).reply(200, { ok: true })

  // perform request
  const r = await fetch(U + '/' + DB,)

  // parse response as JSON
  const j = await r.json()
  console.log(j)
}

main()
```

The above code now has its HTTP "fetch" request intercepted with mocked response.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to get the mocking to work. I am not sure the sample above is doing what it is intended to do.  I think it's actually making a call to localhost.  I haven't been able to use MockAgent to mock the fetch call.  I keep getting the result of the request (which is a google error page in this example).  It should be equivalent as the code above, but I changed the url.  When I had localhost I got fetch errors (since it wasn't being intercepted).

```
const { MockAgent, setGlobalDispatcher, } = require('undici');
test('test', async ()=>{
  // constants
  const U = 'http://www.google.com'
  const DB = 'users'

  const mockAgent = new MockAgent()
  const mockPool = mockAgent.get(U)
  setGlobalDispatcher(mockAgent)

    // intercept GET /users requests
  mockPool.intercept({ path: '/' + DB }).reply(200, { ok: true })
  const opts = { method: 'GET' };
  // perform request
  const r = await fetch(U + '/' + DB,opts)
  // parse response as JSON
  const j = await r.text()
  console.log(j)
});
```

Comment: The domain name "localhost" can interpreted as an IPv6 in newer Node.js versions, which is why my example code uses "127.0.0.1". I've just re-tested the code in my answer and it works just fine, returning a mocked response.

Comment: I had to require `fetch` from undici (instead of using the native nodejs `fetch`) in order for the mock pool to successfully intercept the request.